# Website giving message content must be contained by landmark error

Tags: html

I'm using something called the AXE browser to improve accessibility on my website. Every page seems to have the 'content must be contained by landmark error. Has anyone seen this error? My understanding is that it has to do with their system thinking that I have content outside of html tags.

https://www.mannsjewelers.com/

Comment: What URLs for? Hope not spamming. Do you expect people to visits site and test?

Comment: I was just interested in finding out how people defined a landmark in html. I never did find out a solution to this error.